# Using polymorphism in C# using Dictionary of class Map

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a set of inherited classes say A1, A2, A3, A4, ..., AN from base class A. Now I want to create a map and instantiate a class based on the type
Something like this:

```
Dictionary<int, Type> map = new Dictionary<int, Type> {
    {1, A1.class}, 
    {2, A2.class},
    ...
    {N, AN.class},
}
```

is it possible to determine type and then instantiate using this type of code.

```
gameObject.AddComponent<T>()
```

Comment: `A1.class` is java syntax. In c# it's `typeof(A1)`

Answer (score 0):

You can easily add components with function:
[`gameObject.AddComponent(Type)`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.AddComponent.html)

Beware: type should derive from `Component`.

Example (tested on Unity 2020.1.0f1):

```cs
[ContextMenu(nameof(AddComponents))]
public void AddComponents()
{
    var componentMap = new Dictionary<int, Type>()
    {
        {1, typeof(Rigidbody2D)},
        {2, typeof(BoxCollider2D)},
    };

    foreach (var component in componentMap)
    {
        gameObject.AddComponent(component.Value);
    }
}
```